# Validation errors texts don't appear

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class with 2 properties

```
[StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "User name can't be longer than 8 chars!")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Must be filled!")]
public string NickName { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Must be filled!")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

and I have this Partial view, the user inserts his details and presses the sumbit button.

```
    NickName:
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NickName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NickName)
</div>

<div>
    Password:
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)
</div>

<button type="submit">Log In</button>
```

This is my Post Action,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(ShortUser u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
    {
        if (u.PassMatchUser())
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u.NickName, true);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error","Username / Password inncorect!");
        }
            return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
    }
```

If I insert invalid values the validation texts don't appear.

Comment: Did you check if `ModelState.IsValid` in your action? It tells you if any model errors have been added to ModelState. Can you share your action and complete form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set validation summary to on

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
@Html.EnableClientValidation()
```

On your partial view.

Answer (score 0):

Surround it within a **form** block.

```
<form>
. . .
</form>
```

or

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ . . . }
```

And also make sure you are loading jquery, jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive

Answer (score 0):

There is no true required for ModelState
Change

`if(ModelState.IsValid==true) -> if(ModelState.IsValid)`

Make sure the following :

- Returning the View if ModelState is not Valid.

  return View();
- Model in view and Model you returning in Post Action should be same.
- Make sure you are loading jquery, jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive

  ```
      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")">
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

put your partial view code inside a beginform

eg:
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn","Your Controller name", FormMethod.Post)) 
{

///partial view codes

}